# show related taxonomy blocks

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I wanted to show related taxonomy content in my page and I found this:

http://www.metachunk.com/blog/adding-related-content-view-drupal-7

and it worked perfectly. I wanted to know how it worked basically i.e the 5th step i.e

> Configuration on this filter: -> When the filter value is NOT in the
>   URL: -> Provide default value -> Type: Taxonomy Term ID from URL ->
>   under that, check the box "Load default filter from node page, that's
>   good for related taxonomy blocks." -> now check the boxes of the
>   taxonomies you want involved here

He says get Taxonomy term ID from URL and then says Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks.

Basically what is it doing here ??   Is is trying to tell to block here that get the term ID from the given URL page's term ID selected?

Comment: The site is under maintenance mode. Pleade insert the solution of the given link in to your quedtion.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means that when you include the view as block on a node page, it will get the term id from the page's taxonomy terms (magically) even though the term id is not really on the page's URL path.

I agree that the description for that option is really confusing.